# Xcode 8.2 app Crash -[viewcontroller .cxx_destruct] symbolicated crash report

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash-reports, crittercism

App is experiencing following crash and unable to understand the cause behind of this crash. This crash report I got it from App Store. This is the crash report screenshot

[image: -[viewcontroller .cxx_destruct] symbolicated crash report]

It is mostly affecting on iOS 10.2. In this class I'm using Google Maps, Pageviewcontroller and Timer. So, anyone can tell me how to figure out it?

Comment: please you exceptional Break points

Comment: This crash report I got it from App Store. While testing/debugging I'm not getting this issue/crash.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel Ask them to provide steps to reproduce as you are not able to, they will help, or they must have given steps to reproduce check their response carefully.

Comment: I got this report by making archive and clicked on crashes segment button. Then I selected the version. @iphonic To whom I have to ask? Can you guide me?

Comment: @AntonyRaphel I thought you got this in iTunesConnect section by Apple, so I was telling you ask Apple for the steps. Though the crash looks like memory leak in your code.

Comment: @iphonic, Under iTunesConnect also I got the crash count. Yeah, even I'm thinking same as ARC issue. But, difficult to find out where it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crash is happening due to fetching user current location from Google Maps by using **addObserver** `forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew`.

While dealloc Google Maps, that time you need to remove this Observer. Otherwise app will crash with following error

> NSInternalInconsistencyException: An instance 0x1759f350 of class GMSMapView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (  Context: 0x0, Property: 0x177a4490> )

you need to addObserver before adding Google Maps to mapView like following:

```
// Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
[mapView_ addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
            context:NULL];

self.view = mapView_;

// Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
});

#pragma mark - KVO updates

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {
if (!firstLocationUpdate_) {
// If the first location update has not yet been received, then jump to that
// location.
  firstLocationUpdate_ = YES;
  CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
mapView_.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate
                                                 zoom:14];
 }
}
```

then add this code also for removing the observer

```
- (void)dealloc {
[mapView_ removeObserver:self
            forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
               context:NULL];
}
```

for more details: [Google Maps iOS SDK, Getting Current Location of user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994202/4831524)